# CGAL::Surface_mesh - Accessing face/vertex using an integer index?

Tags: c, cgal

From the [user manual](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh/index.html) of the CGAL `Surface_mesh` class:

> the data structure uses integer indices as descriptors for vertices,
>   halfedges, edges and faces

I am interested in accessing a certain face/edge/vertex based on it's integer index, but cannot find how this is done.
Iterators obviously work, but I don't want to iterate a known number of times just to get to the relevant `face_index`/`vertex_index` if I can access based on an integer face/vertex index known a-priori.

Can someone please explain how (if actually possible) to use the integer indexing if I want to access the i-th face "directly" (without iterating)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

  `unsigned int i = 33;
  Surface_mesh::Face_index fi(i);`

Comment: I actually have tried this before, but got irrelevant outputs... I guess my mistake was elsewhere and I assumed the problem was there. Thanks.

Comment: Note that all the indices are not necessarily contiguous, in particular if you have removed some elements some indices might be invalid. You can use the function [`is_valid(fi)`](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Surface_mesh/classCGAL_1_1Surface__mesh.html#ab1734f0c4dfa5f08b4ee1be0449b572e) to check.